# Parent and child dimension calculations

Tags: html, border, margin, css

Can someone help me understand why #child is not the same size as #parent?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='parent' style='border: 1px solid black'>
            <div id='child' style='background-color: #888888'>
                <p>Here is some content</p>
                <div id='grandchild' style='margin-bottom: 1em'>
                    <p>A little more content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

Margin Collapsing. Jeroen's answer pointed me to the [W3C box model specs for collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), which gave me a headache, and didn't quite answer the question of the border (which Oded first pointed out). Then I found [this article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing) and pieced the solution together (I'm talking about just the top margins, but this exact same solution applies to the bottom margins).

1. When two [block-level] elements' vertical margins are touching, *the larger margin is used* and the smaller margin is discarded.
2. Everything in your code is considered a block-level element, including the `<html>` and `<body>` tags.
3. The `<body>` has a default `margin-top` of 8px inside its parent `<html>` element.
4. The first `<p>` tag has a default `margin-top` of 16px.
5. Margin collapsing isn't confined to siblings, so the `<p>` tag starts to check against its parent tag's position and margins.
6. The `#child` element has a `margin-top` of 0. The `<p>` top margin is touching the `#child` top margin, so they collapse to a single 16px margin (16 > 0). The `<p>` tag's 16px margin "pushes through" and acts as a margin for the `#child` tag.
7. The 16px margin from `<p>` is still checking for margins directly above it. Next up *would* be the `#parent` tag, which also has a margin-top of 0.
8. **BUT, The 1px border on `#parent` prevents `<p>` from going any further.** `<p>` isn't going to run into any more margins above it, because it's touching the 1px border. So the collapsing stops inside the top border of `#parent`.
9. The 16px top-margin is rendered, and underneath is the `#child` tag whose 0px margin was collapsed.

That's why the `#parent` box is 32px taller than the `#child` box: The `<p>` margins "crashed through" until they hit something that wasn't a margin (the 1px border). So, what happens if the 1px border on `#parent` hadn't been there to stop the collapsing?

1. Follow steps 1-7 above.
2. `<p>` 's top margin runs into the `#parent` element's 0px top margin. Again, `<p>` is the bigger margin (16 vs 0), so the collapsing continues upward.
3. `<p>` 's top margin hits the `<body>` tag. The `<body>` has a default top margin of 8px. The `<p>` tag is bigger, so now the `<body>` tag has "inherited" the 16px top margin, and the 8px is discarded.
4. The `<p>` top margin reaches the `<html>` tag. Since `<html>` is the root element, the collapsing stops here. The `<body>` tag renders with a 16px top margin, and the `#parent`, `#child`, and `<p>` elements all render beneath; `<p>` is snug inside the `#parent` box because the margin crashed through it.

The reason why this took me so long to figure out is the same reason I hadn't heard of collapsing margins until today: **Firebug doesn't clearly depict collapsing margins**. In Firebug, the `<p>` tag still shows that it's holding the 16px top margin. This is true. However, there's no indication that any collapsing has taken place--the `<body>` tag still reports an 8px top border, even though it's been discarded.

I'm glad I know this now; it clarifies much confusion I've had about page layouts.

---

Edit:

[The article I referenced](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing) is really worth the read. Not only did it give me the info I needed for the answer, it also details how in IE7, the `<body>` tag doesn't participate in border collapsing. That explains a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Because your parent div has a border of 1px around itself, and the child doesn't.

This adds 2 pixels to the width and height of the parent div.

Comment: Why does the border cause that? I would think that adding a border would not affect the dimensions, save by the thickness of the border. Edit: in case this comment wasn't clear; yes, you are correct that the border is the culprit in changing the dimensions. I just don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the standard margins on the `p` and the `bottom-margin` on `#grandchild`. They collapse with the standard margin of the `body`.

You can reset the margins on `body`, `p`, etc. and use paddings instead of margins to avoid that; paddings don´t collapse.

Comment: How does the `border: 1px solid black` cause the different behavior?

Comment: @Jake, that's a very good question, the answer is probably somewhere in the documentation of the W3C where they are talking about the box model and collapsing margins. Where boxes are concerned, I *normally* rely on paddings as margins can cause a bad headache...